# Google kickstart 2021 L shaped plots cannot understand what is wrong here?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So here is the code I wrote for the question(https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000436140/000000000068c509#problem). For the sample input I am getting the right answer but it is not clearing test set 1.

I have created the code such that it checks for "1" up down right and left for each element of array and sees whether from that junction an L can be made.

For reference these are the conditions in the question:

"A segment is called "good" if all the cells in the segment contain only 1s.

An "L-shape" is defined as an unordered pair of segments, which has all the following properties:

Each of the segments must be a "good" segment.
The two segments must be perpendicular to each other.
The segments must share one cell that is an endpoint of both segments.
Segments must have length at least 2.
The length of the longer segment is twice the length of the shorter segment."

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int t, u;
    cin >> t;
    for (u = 1; u <= t; u++) {
        int i, j, k, l = 0, a[40][40], r, c, right = 0, left = 0, up = 0, down = 0, downc, upc, lc, rc;
        cin >> r >> c;
        for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                cin >> a[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] == 1) {
                    right = 0;
                    left = 0;
                    up = 0;
                    down = 0;
                    downc = 0;
                    upc = 0;
                    lc = 0;
                    rc = 0;
                    for (k = i; k < r; k++) {
                        if (a[k][j] == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                            down++;
                    }
                    for (k = i; k >= 0; k--) {
                        if (a[k][j] == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                            up++;
                    }
                    for (k = j; k < c; k++) {
                        if (a[i][k] == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                            right++;
                    }
                    for (k = j; k >= 0; k--) {
                        if (a[i][k] == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                            left++;
                    }
                    if (!(up > 1 && down > 1 && right > 1 && left > 1)) {
                        downc = down;
                        upc = up;
                        rc = right;
                        lc = left;
                        if (up >= 2) {
                            if (right >= 4) {
                                while ((upc * 2) > right)
                                    upc--;
                                l = l + upc - 1;
                            }
                            upc = up;
                            if (left >= 4) {
                                while ((upc * 2) > left)
                                    upc--;
                                l = l + upc - 1;
                            }
                            upc = up;
                        }
                        if (down >= 2) {
                            if (right >= 4) {
                                while ((downc * 2) > right)
                                    downc--;
                                l = l + downc - 1;
                            }
                            downc = down;
                            if (left >= 4) {
                                while ((downc * 2) > left)
                                    downc--;
                                l = l + downc - 1;
                            }
                            downc = down;
                        }
                        if (right >= 2) {
                            if (up >= 4) {
                                while ((rc * 2) > up)
                                    rc--;
                                l = l + rc - 1;
                            }
                            rc = right;
                            if (down >= 4) {
                                while ((rc * 2) > down)
                                    rc--;
                                l = l + rc - 1;
                            }
                            rc = right;
                        }
                        if (left >= 2) {
                            if (up >= 4) {
                                while ((lc * 2) > up)
                                    lc--;
                                l = l + lc - 1;
                            }
                            lc = left;
                            if (down >= 4) {
                                while ((lc * 2) > down)
                                    lc--;
                                l = l + lc - 1;
                            }
                            lc = left;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Case #" << u << ": " << l << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If start by formatting your code properly, http://format.krzaq.cc/ can help or just use the format function of your ide. Next split your code into functions, 5 or 6 levels of nesting is far too many to make your code readable. Once you've done that it's time to find some inputs that fail, try thinking of some edge cases

Comment: Thank you for the link. I formatted the code using it. For the readability I will try to use function from now on(I didnt had to write such long programs till now so skipped using func.).Lets see if I find the bug while re writing the code using functions. Also for the edge cases I tried multiple different inputs but it seems to work for me.

Comment: You should really choose more meaningful names for variables, if you want others to read your code; most IDEs provide some functionality for renaming vars so you don't need to type long var names when writing the code initially. Also imho variables only used in a loop body and in the condition/post iteration statement should be declared in the loops init statement, but that may just be personal preference. However I assume you get a segfault for Test set 2 (grids up to 1000 X 1000)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the issue finally :
There was no need for " if (!(up > 1 && down > 1 && right > 1 && left > 1)) {.....}"
But still this code is too time consuming to run 1000x1000 grid case. Hence it fails test 2.
Edit: It was a mistake on my end. I bounded the array as 40x40. On changing it to a[1000][1000] it ran both tests successfully. Congos to me.